# Which (South) East-Asian contries are the cleanest?

Tags: culture, southeast-asia, asia, hygiene, east-asia

I had been in Thailand recently and I was negatively surprised with how dirty the country is.

Garbage was everywhere - along the roads, in the temples and museums, even in the sea.

I expected the country to be a clean one, especially in turist destinations. They do not allow people to wear the shorts in their temples, but ignore large hills of garbage just next to the entrance!

While there I was told that there is even more garbage in the neighbouring Cambodia and Laos. On the other hand, accounts on the internet claim that Singapore and North Korea are the cleanest.

I wonder whether these accounts are correct?

Comment: I would say Singapore is the cleanest so far. They have a really strict rule about litter law.

Comment: Really not a problem you're trying to solve, let alone a question that can be objectively and/or accurately answered without more specific criteria.

Comment: I just finished typing in my answer and then closed :D

Comment: @greg121 by all means please type it as a comment

Comment: @greg121 or in the meta

Comment: In conclusion I was referring to the Environmental Performance Index. http://epi.yale.edu/epi2012/rankings

Comment: @greg121 it lists Thailand as a strong performer, but it definitely does not account for garbage which is everywhere in Thailand.

Comment: you are right it doesn't take this into account but it was the only ranking I could find in that context

Comment: As a guy from Bangkok who lives in New York, I think any big cities are quite the same (besides, say, Tokyo and Singapore because of the reasons that others have mentioned.) In general, tropical countries look dirtier because of heat, humidity, and possibly your definition of cleanliness. For many people in Thailand, public places are not of anyone's interest but private places are usually clean.

Comment: Since the question also seems to cover East Asia I can say that Thailand is not far behind Malaysia, which is a bit behind Singapore. But Singapore is not as clean as you might expect if you're heard of their policies but not been there. Now China is much worse than Thailand and Japan and Korea are probably cleaner than Singapore, though both have differences in things such as garbage collection which can make them dirty compared to western countries in some areas at some times.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting question, though I don't see the relationship between not wearing shorts in temples and garbage outside.

As @toy already commented, Singapore is the cleanest due to its strict litter laws.
North Korea is probably also very clean, though that's not considered part of Southeast Asia.
Japan is also quite litter-free, though also not part of Southeast Asia.

Comment: In addition to Japan and North Korea, Finland is very clean, though it's not considered part of Southeast Asia, either. Also, Switzerland.

Comment: The question seems to be asking about both East Asia and Southeast Asia. If it's only about Southeast Asia then the parentheses around (South) need to be removed.